# Unable to approve API permissions from API Management page

Tags: spfx-webparts, api, webapi

I created a custom web part that calls a web API I created. When I deployed the web part, I went to approve the required permissions and received the following errors:

> [HTTP]:500 - [CorrelationId]:180c139f-a0f1-9000-115d-8cfb7dfd8498 [Version]:16.0.0.19416
>   [HTTP]:500 - [CorrelationId]:1a0c139f-b052-9000-728d-d74eebad335c [Version]:16.0.0.19416

See the below screenshot:

[image: API Management Error]

Why can't I approve the permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tenant administrator was able to approve the permissions without issue. I was made a SharePoint admin so I'm not sure why I couldn't but the issue is resolved nonetheless.